# From igraph to ggplot object

Tags: r, ggplot2, igraph

I've built a dendrogram using ggraph and igraph.

```
library(ggraph)
library(igraph)
EL <- read.csv("EL2.csv", sep=";",header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
ELM <-as.matrix(EL)
mygraph <- graph_from_data_frame(ELM)
ggraph(mygraph, layout = 'dendrogram', circular = TRUE) + 
  geom_edge_diagonal() +
  geom_node_point() +
  theme_void()
```

However, I need the underlying data for nodes and edges to recreate it in Tableau.

I wanted to use ggplot_build, but that requires a ggplot object. In order to create that I'm trying to use ig2ggplot, but it returns an error:

```
ig2ggplot(mygraph, dfOnly = FALSE, labels = FALSE, metab = TRUE)
```

Error in layout.norm(g$layout, xmax = 1, xmin = 0, ymin = 0, ymax = 1) : 
  `layout' not a matrix

Does that mean I have to turn my igraph into a matrix? Because the plot looks exactly like I want it to look. I'm just trying to get hold off the underlying data. Any help would be appreciated on how to turn my igraph into a ggplot.

Edit: data with dput() (sorry, haven't used this before so I don't know if it's correct)

> dput(EL)
>   structure(list(from = c("Indo-European", "Albanian", "Gheg", 
>   "Albanian", "Tosk", "Tosk", "Tosk", "Indo-European", "Armenian", 
>   "Armenian", "Indo-European", "Balto-Slavic", "Baltic", "Eastern", 
>   "Eastern", "Eastern", "Eastern", "Baltic", "Western", "Balto-Slavic", 
>   "Slavic", "East", "East", "East", "East", "Slavic", "South", 
>   "South Eastern", "South Eastern", "South Eastern", "South", "South Western", 
>   "South Western", "South Western", "South Western", "South Western", 
>   "Slavic", "West", "Czech-Slovak", "Czech-Slovak", "West", "Lechitic", 
>   "Lechitic", "Lechitic", "West", "Sorbian", "Sorbian", "Indo-European", 
>   "Celtic", "Insular", "Brythonic", "Brythonic", "Brythonic", "Insular", 
>   "Goidelic", "Goidelic", "Goidelic", "Indo-European", "Germanic", 
>   "North Germanic", "East Scandinavian", "East Scandinavian", "Danish-Swedish", 
>   "Danish-Bokmal", "Danish-Swedish", "Danish-Riksmal", "Danish-Swedish", 
>   "North Germanic", "West Scandinavian", "West Scandinavian", "Germanic", 
>   "West Germanic", "English", "English", "West Germanic", "Frisian", 
>   "Frisian", "Frisian", "West Germanic", "High German", "German", 
>   "German", "Middle German", "East Middle German", "East Middle German", 
>   "East Middle German", "East Middle German", "Middle German", 
>   "West Middle German", "West Middle German", "West Middle German", 
>   "West Middle German", "Moselle Franconian", "German", "Upper German", 
>   "Upper German", "Alemannic", "Alemannic", "Alemannic", "Alemannic", 
>   "Upper German", "Bavarian-Austrian", "Bavarian-Austrian", "Bavarian-Austrian", 
>   "Bavarian-Austrian", "High German", "Yiddish", "Yiddish", "West Germanic", 
>   "Low Saxon-Low Franconian", "Low Franconian", "Low Franconian", 
>   "Low Franconian", "Low Franconian", "Low Franconian", "Low Saxon-Low Franconian", 
>   "Low Saxon", "Low Saxon", "Low Saxon", "Low Saxon", "Low Saxon", 
>   "Low Saxon", "Low Saxon", "Low Saxon", "Low Saxon", "Low Saxon", 
>   "Low Saxon", "Indo-European", "Greek", "Attic", "Attic", "Attic", 
>   "Attic", "Attic", "Greek", "Doric"), to = c("Albanian", "Gheg", 
>   "Gheg Albanian", "Tosk", "Arbereshe Albanian", "Arvanitika Albanian", 
>   "Tosk Albanian", "Armenian", "Armenian (language)", "Western Armenian", 
>   "Balto-Slavic", "Baltic", "Eastern", "Latgalian", "Standard Latvian", 
>   "Lithuanian", "Samogitian", "Western", "Prussian", "Slavic", 
>   "East", "Belarusian", "Russian", "Rusyn", "Ukrainian", "South", 
>   "South Eastern", "Bulgarian", "Macedonian", "Church Slavonic", 
>   "South Western", "Bosnian", "Croatian", "Montenegrin", "Serbian", 
>   "Slovene", "West", "Czech-Slovak", "Czech", "Slovak", "Lechitic", 
>   "Kashubian", "Polish", "Silesian", "Sorbian", "Lower Sorbian", 
>   "Upper Sorbian", "Celtic", "Insular", "Brythonic", "Breton", 
>   "Cornish", "Welsh", "Goidelic", "Irish", "Manx", "Scottish Gaelic", 
>   "Germanic", "North Germanic", "East Scandinavian", "Oevdalian", 
>   "Danish-Swedish", "Danish-Bokmal", "Norwegian", "Danish-Riksmal", 
>   "Danish", "Swedish", "West Scandinavian", "Faroese", "Icelandic", 
>   "West Germanic", "English", "English (language)", "Scots", "Frisian", 
>   "Frisian (language)", "Northern Frisian", "Saterfrisian", "High German", 
>   "German", "Hunsrik", "Middle German", "East Middle German", "Standard German", 
>   "Upper Saxon", "Lower Silesian", "Wymysory", "West Middle German", 
>   "Pennsylvania German", "Palatinate Franconian", "Ripurian", "Moselle Franconian", 
>   "Luxembourgish", "Upper German", "Eastern Franconian", "Alemannic", 
>   "Colonia Tovar German", "Swiss German", "Swabian", "Walser", 
>   "Bavarian-Austrian", "Bavarian", "Cimbrian", "Hutterisch", "Mocheno", 
>   "Yiddish", "Eastern Yiddish", "Western Yiddish", "Low Saxon-Low Franconian", 
>   "Low Franconian", "Afrikaans", "Dutch", "Limburgish", "Vlaams", 
>   "Zeeuws", "Low Saxon", "Achterhoeks", "Drents", "Gronings", "Plautdietsch", 
>   "Sallands", "East Frisian Low Saxon", "Low Saxon", "Stellingwerfs", 
>   "Twents", "Veluws", "Westphalien", "Greek", "Attic", "Cappadocian Greek", 
>   "Greek (language)", "Ancient Greek", "Pontic", "Yevanic", "Doric", 
>   "Tsakonian")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -136L))

Comment: Please edit your question and add some data (using `dput()`).

Comment: Done. I hope that was the correct way to use dput(), but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 4):

a layout tells `igraph` where the **x** and **y** location for each node is for a plot. *ig2ggplot* requires that a layout is stored as a graph attribute. You will need to do something like this

```
mygraph <- igraph::graph_from_data_frame(ELM) #create a graph
mylayout <- igraph::layout_as_tree(mygraph, circular = T) #create a circular layout

mygraph$layout = mylayout #store layout as a graph attribute


#another gotcha is that ig2ggplot needs both vertex names and vertex labels. 
#as of now you just have vertex names. 
V(mygraph)$label = V(mygraph)$name #store label as a vertex attrbute


MetamapsDB::ig2ggplot(mygraph, 
                      dfOnly = FALSE, 
                      labels = FALSE, 
                      metab = TRUE ) + 
    theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks!!! A follow-up question on this one: is it possible to extend the branches to the deepest level in ggplot? igraph does it automatically and I thought it looked very neat.

Comment: I also found that the coordinates returned through layout_as_tree(mygraph, root = numeric(), circular = TRUE, rootlevel = numeric(), mode = "out", flip.y = TRUE) returns very similar results to your graph when plotted in Tableau. However, I seem to be missing some nodes and will look into it